# Jquery UI css applying even without css files in an Asp Net Mvc 4 Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a terrible nightmare..
In my Asp Net MVC 4 application I am calling the javascripts and css scripts using Bundles.

I did not have success trying to remove a tab border so I decided to remove all jquery ui files from my project and guess what... Jquery UI still works.

The only thing that makes jquery ui stop working is to remove the following from my BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Style/css").Include("~/Style/redmond/*.css"));
```

So I presume it is loading the css´s from another files but I don´t know where they are.

My last attempt was to remove reference for Jquery and Jquery UI  packages from my project 
and still I get the same behavior

Does anybody ever had the same happening to you? I you do, how can I solve that?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache? The easiest way to check if it is a cache issue is to do Ctrl+F5 in the browser.

Comment: Are you running from within IIS or on the VS development server? In any case, try recycling the application pool in IIS or restarting the VS development server. Also check whether the `<script ...>` tags are still present in the generated HTML - so that you can see where it is loading them from. Furthermore, you can open the Network tab in e.g. Firebug and see what is actually loaded (which css and js files) and where from.

Answer (score 1):

Browser caching a scripts and styles. So scripts and styles will load from cache and working.

Try to clear cache in your borwser:

[Clear cache in browser](http://www.google.pl/#hl=pl&tbo=d&spell=1&q=clear+browser+cache&sa=X&ei=H6ruUK_KO4eNtAbg8YCoBw&ved=0CCgQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.Yms&fp=bfb333c9865f867b&biw=1280&bih=896)

Comment: This is not a cache problem. Other browser has the same behavior